# Column number limitations on custom list edit form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, custom-form

Can any one confirm whether there is a limit on the number of list columns displayed in a custom list edit form created through SPD(2013)?

My scenario is that I am amending a preexisting list by adding a new Choice column.  This column appears correctly in the default New and Edit forms, but steadfastly refuses to get pulled into a custom edit form I am creating in SPD2013.

The column I have added is the 70th in the list, which is well within the specified limits.

Was wondering if anyone else had experienced the same?

BTW, I am operating in SP Online (2013 / v15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been fighting this for days. There is a limit of 70 fields in a custom edit form, and this includes Attachment, Modified, Modified By, Created, Created By. I'm in SP2010, but the issue is also in 2013. Reference the book SharePoint Designer 2010 Unleashed by Hughes, p1329.

You can get around this by editing for form in InfoPath if you have enterprise Sharepoint licensing. Failing that, see if you can reduce the number of form fields somehow. For instance, in our case, there is some information that's entered at item creation but should not be changed thereafter, so we don't need it on the edit form. We can still have it on the Display form.

Another option might be to have multiple edit forms for users who have different roles and who therefore don't need to see every field all at once.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good to know - thanks. I will bear this in mind with future design decisions. I will steer clear of the InfoPath route given that MS are phasing this out